# Initialize typeahead source using data dash attributes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

My typeahead elements have some data attributes that defines url, fields, and another parameters to send to my service.

I'm trying to a access these data attributes in the source function, but no luck.

My typeahead element is defined like this:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" data-url="some_url.json">
```

My javascript to initialize typeahead is this:

```
$("body").find('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: getSource()        
})  

function getSource(){
    var my_url = ???????

    return new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
                url: my_url,
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
              }
        });
}
```

The "this" variable at "getSource" function points to "window".
There is another way to do this, or I need to define an initialization for each typeahed type I have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply iterate over typeahead elements before activating then:

```
$(".typeahead").each(function(){
    var url = $(this).data("url");
    $(this).typeahead(...);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an empty typeahead and use "typeahead:active" event to initialize it:
    $("selector").typeahead()
      .on("typeahead:active", function(){
          var url = $(this).data("url");

```
      //destroy old typeahead
      $(this).unbind("typeahead:active"); 
      $(this).typeahead("destroy");

      //reconstruct typeahead again
      $(this).typeahead(null,
          {
            displayKey: xxx,
            source: url
          });
  }
```

Keep in mind that when you "destroy" your control, it rolls back to original element. So somethings could be lost, like focus.

Another problem is that this event will be fired again in new control. So you need to unbind this event.